# Each jquery get values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach, each

Here I have this code jquery:

```
JSON.stringify($("#vrsta_rada").select2("data"));
```

and I get this JSON file:

```
"[{"id":2,"text":"setva/zasad"},{"id":6,"text":"orezivanje"},{"id":8,"text":"skladistenje"}]"
```

How I can use `.each` function to get this string: `data[0].text, data[1].text` ...
so to get string from JSON above: `setva/zasad, orezivanje, skladistenje`

?

Comment: Start by not stringifying the object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are stringifying the data if you want to manipulate it. So this will work:

```
var data = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data");

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  var text = data[key].text
  //or
  var text = value.text
});
```

Is this what you are looking for? That will iterate through the list. I prefer to use `data[key]` because you can then manipulate the data and it will change the original whereas value only makes a copy.

Comment: i will see now, thyanks

Comment: Better use value.text check my answer

Comment: Why? I've explained my reasoning for using the key above. Your answer is pretty much the same :)

Comment: I get: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: BTW @gmaestro you want to use `JSON.parse`. You can't iterate over a string as far as I'm aware. In your original code you'd just do: `var data = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data")`

Comment: now when I go to alert (text) I get again array and object, not string1!!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   alert(value.text)
});
```

Comment: I get this: var data = JSON.stringify($("#vrednost_rada").select2("data"));
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   alert(value.text)
});
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: @gmaestro Don't stringify your object .Use `var data = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data")`

Comment: I dont get string with this function ... how I can get string ?